# Where does KDE 4 store its keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, kde4

Some Emacs keyboard shortcuts are intercepted by KDE.  I know that KDE lets you configure keyboard shortcuts via GUI, but I am tired of sifting every time all the menus.  I would like to open the files where KDE stores its shortcuts, both at the system level and at the user level, and change all the shortcuts that interfere with Emacs once for all.

I am using KDE 4.14.2.

Comment: Just a note for current KDE5: it's stored in ~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The global ones are in `~/.kde4/share/config/kglobalshortcutsrc`.
Different apps/services may have specific ones in their own config files - many in the same dir.

Note: the `~/.kde4` path is seen on OpenSUSE, on other distributions the path may exist under `~/.kde` instead.

Comment: I have customized some keyboard shortcuts, but there is no `~/.kde4/share/config/` directory.

Comment: My KDE is 4.14.6, I doubt that changed in between. Maybe opensuse (I'm on 13.2) customisation? Maybe some other location under ~/.kde4? Or ~/.kde (this used to be the default years ago, maybe ~/.kde4 itself is a suse customisation from when they shipped with both KDE3 and KDE4)?